# sharepoint online CSOM is not working on production server

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I write code to read folder and download it on local, code is working on local machine but when deployed same code on production server it does not every time it throw below exception

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Below is my code snippet

```
public void crmtodownload()
        {

            string userName = "<sharepointuser>";
            string password = "<sharepointpassword>";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            try
            {
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                using (var clientContext = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("<sharepoint url>"))
                {
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                    Web web = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(web, a => a.ServerRelativeUrl);                   
                    FileCollection fileCollection = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("<sharepoint folder path>").Files;                                     
                    clientContext.Load(fileCollection);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCollection)
                    {
                        generatefile(file, clientContext);
                    }
                  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Exception"] = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        public void generatefile(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file, ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var folderpath = @"c:\downloadfolder";
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderpath))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
                }
                string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.Name);
                using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(folderpath + @"\" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(folderpath + @"\" + file.Name);
            }
        }
```

Same code work on local machine but when after deploying this on production it started to throw exception at code line **clientContext.ExecuteQuery();**, please help to resolve this.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: I am getting the same, with code that had been running for years and no changes, starting from 29 June. Can connect perfectly from local machine, from production server get this error. Seems like maybe there is some kind of block/firewall/throttling in place?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online "For all other requests, including CSOM or REST calls, SharePoint Online returns HTTP status code 429 ("Too many requests") or 503 ("Server Too Busy") and the requests will fail." - I haven't seen these errors specifically, I get "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." and "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: There is some useful code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online to dig out more info, but it still doesn't resolve anything for me - the ex.Response property is null and hence there is no StatusCode to be determined.